# Thread-safe and fast adding 20000 items to a ListView in WinForms

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview

I have a custom WinForms control which contains a ListView which has to load up to 20000 items, read from a CSV file.

I am using CSVHelper to load the file in a separate thread, then I invoke `listView1.Add` on the UI thread to add them to that `ListView`.

My current implementation (as you can see in the code) is probably bad, and thus very slow when it comes to add those 20000 items into the `ListView`.

Note that I am fairly new to thread-safe and multi-threading development.

This is the entire code of my custom control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using CsvHelper;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyDevTaskDesktop
{
    public partial class MyCSVReaderControl : UserControl
    {
        List<Product> loadedProducts;

        public MyCSVReaderControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CsvFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void CsvFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            TxtFilename.Text = CsvFileDialog.FileName;

            listView1.Items.Clear();

            listView1.Visible = false;
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
            listView1.GridLines = true;
            listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;

            listView1.Columns.Add("#", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Filename", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Id", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Quantity", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Price", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Right);

            LoadCSVThread();

            loadedProducts = new List<Product>();
        }
        public void LoadCSV()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(CsvFileDialog.FileName))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                csv.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
                csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
                csv.Configuration.AutoMap<CsvProduct>();
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

                var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvProduct>().ToList();

                int index = 0;
                string firstFilename = null;
                Color foreColor;

                foreach (CsvProduct product in records)
                {
                    index++;

                    if (firstFilename == null)
                    {
                        firstFilename = product.Filename;
                    }

                    foreColor = (firstFilename == product.Filename) ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;

                    loadedProducts.Add(new Product()
                    {
                        Color = foreColor,
                        Index = index,
                        Filename = product.Filename,
                        Id = product.Id,
                        Quantity = product.Quantity,
                        Price = product.Price
                    });

                    if (LblProcess.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        LblProcess.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                        {
                            LblProcess.Text = "Processed " + index + " records...";
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (LblProcess.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    LblProcess.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                    {
                        LblProcess.Text = "Finished!";
                        LblProcess.Visible = false;
                    });
                }

                if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                    {
                        listView1.Visible = true;

                        listView1.BeginUpdate();

                        foreach (var item in loadedProducts)
                        {
                            ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                            {
                                item.Index.ToString(),
                                item.Filename,
                                item.Id,
                                item.Quantity.ToString(),
                                item.Price.ToString()
                            });

                            listItem.ForeColor = item.Color;

                            listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
                            //listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
                        }

                        listView1.Sort();
                        listView1.EndUpdate();
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        public void LoadCSVThread()
        {
            Thread worker = new Thread(LoadCSV);
            worker.IsBackground = true;
            worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            worker.Start();
        }

        private class Product
        {
            public Color Color { get; set; }
            public int Index { get; set; }
            public string Filename { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }
        }

        private class CsvProduct
        {
            public string Filename { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with `async/await`, but ended up even slower for reasons unclear to me yet. When I used those, nothing in the UI got updated as it iterates through the array.

I know that my approach to fill up the `loadedProducts` `List` first and then iterate that list to update the view, is bad, but currently that produces fastest result - best what I could do, because if I update the UI while I update `LblProcess` label text, it gets slower, double-wise.

So, what is the best way to add 20000 or more items to a `ListView`?

Comment: My Y response to your X problem is to rethink why you need to add 20k+ items to a single control, any control. Perhaps some other UI paradigm would be better?

Comment: Did you try without the progress display ("Processed " + index + " records...")? Or only every 100 records?

Comment: @TanveerBadar I know, but this is a task requirement. I come from a web development background and I would never do it this way to fill up any control, but I am clueless on how to continue with this in WinForms.

Comment: @KlausGütter It's very fast without any UI updates from that separate thread, but I will try to update them on each 100th iteration.

Comment: Have you tried with background workers? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-3.1) Btw, as @TanveerBadar says, I would ask myself if the user really needs those 20k items on the list or if it's just going to see a few each time. Maybe categorize them?

Comment: Yes. Regardless of requirements of my task, I will create a pagination functionality so I'll display 200 per page, and user can shift between pages as they like.